# Ввести строчную величину, состоящую из букв, цифр и арифметических операций. Удалить из этой строки цифры и знаки арифметических операций

Tags: python, удаление-символов

мои попытки:

```
x = 'fdgujndniogf2134+-123'
print (''.join([y for y in x if y.isdigit()]))
```

- выводит только цифры, не повторяющиеся
  так же пытался через функцию re но не получалось

Comment: Удивительно, добавляешь в результат только цифры и только цифры и выводятся.... 

Comment: А при чём тут повторяющиеся, про них в условии ничего не сказано ведь было?

Answer (score 1):

Python. Через **регулярные выражения**

```py
import re 
 
x = 'fdgujndniogf2134+-123' 
result = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-zЁёА-Яа-я]', '', x) 
print(result) # fdgujndniogf
```

Метод `sub` меняет все символы из 3 параметра, соответствующие шаблону(1 параметру), на строку из 2 параметра и возвращает переделанную строку. То есть все попадающие под шаблон символы превратятся в пустую строку.

**Что обозначает шаблон?**

`r` нужен чтобы `\` воспринимался как обычный символ, а не служебный. Здесь ставить `r` перед шаблоном необязательно, но лучше поставить.

`-` диапазон символов. Например a-z означает все строчные(маленькие) буквы английского алфавита от a до z включительно. A-Z означает заглавные буквы. То же самое и с русским алфавитом, но ё Ё нужно написать отдельно, они не попадают в а-я А-Я.

`[]` позволяет захватить сразу несколько диапазонов.

`^` инверсирует(меняет на противоположное) всё, что находится в `[]`.

То есть под этот шаблон попадает всё, кроме(`^`) заглавных и строчных букв английского и русского алфавитов.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задание то это можно сделать вот так:

```
x = 'fdgujndniogf2134+-123'


def letter_filter(s):
    result = ""
    for item in s:
        if item.isalpha():
            result += item
    return result

print(letter_filter(x))
```

Или так:

```
result = ''.join([item for item in x if item.isalpha()])
print(result)
```

Comment: Во втором варианте ошибка

Comment: @Эникейщик Исправил. :-)